# Debug 'env' in Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, env, clearance

I want to check the value of `env[:clearance]` to see why something is broken.

How can I do this. I tried `puts`:

```
  config.user.current = Proc.new { env[:clearance].current_user }
  puts "ENV[:CLEARANCE]: #{env[:clearance]}"
```

but that gets: `undefined local variable or method`env' for main:Object (NameError)`

How can I get some visibility into the `env` hash in this situation? BTW this is loosely related to the [Clearance gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ENV[:clearance]` instead of `env[:clearance]` ?

Comment: perhaps but that doesn't seem to work either. following [their advice](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/#integrating-with-rack-applications).

Comment: I think `env` is a helper method, which you can't access before *initializer* is loaded and you are trying to access it inside [initializer](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/#configure) only..

Comment: well, fwiw, I'm trying to access `env` in a Proc inside another initializer (not the initializer for Clearance, itself)

Comment: because it's a Proc maybe it can't be debugged easily?!?

Comment: Well, try this simple Ruby code - `p = Proc.new { x }
x = 10 p.call` and see what it throws.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve or what `config.user.current` is (it's not Clearance). One problem however is that you are trying to use the method `env` in the proc where it will not be defined. The proc has its own scope.

If you just want to see what ENV is after the clearance middleware has run the simplest thing to do would be to put a binding.pry or debugger statement inside a controller and access `env` that way.

The clearance environment is set by middleware in response to a request. It will not be set in an initializer.